"Who" is to "whose", like "which" is to …?
As far as I can tell, "whose" is a possessive form of "who".
Is there a similar possessive form for "which" or "what"? Sometimes my brain has reached for "which's" only to give up in bewilderment.

Please see Peter Shor's answer. Normally you just use whose, but not in interrogative contexts.

"Which's" makes me smile. It would be fun to pair it with "where's," "that's," and so forth. "That's that. And that's that's. Here's here's; where's where's?"

Why not Post three or four examples… please?
